# How do I complile a .java file function and read arg from cmd line linux?

Tags: command-line, java, php

I have a function written in java to read a string and return the processed results.

I am using php and instead of re-writing the java function in php, I would like to make a shell_exec call and get the results returned from java via command line in Linux.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 2):

Since your title also mentions compiling, and while I'm assuming you have the java source code you want to use - I figured I'd make this as complete as possible so I also provided sample source code.

the directory structure for simplicity is /mainTest, e.g. root and a folder called mainTest.  In it is a java source file called phpFunction.java

The java source code is as follows

```
package mainTest;

public class phpFunction {

    public phpFunction() {

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //our input is a string, example "25", convert it into a number
        int inputArg1 = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        //will hold a value to be output
        int outputValue = -1;

        //call a method with our input
        outputValue= multiplyInput(inputArg1);

        //print the output to std out
        System.out.println(outputValue);

    }

    //simply multiplies the input value by 2, returns results
    private static int multiplyInput(int inputValue){
        return inputValue*2;
    }

}
```

The source code as indicated in comments simply takes a single value as input and multiplies it by two and sends the results to standard out.

To compile it, you need to make sure you have the java jdk installed, you can check by doing

```
locate javac
```

If you dont have it installed, install it (you could also compile the code somewhere else that might have it installed)

From the root directory run

```
javac mainTest/phpFunction.java
```

You'll end up with a phpFunction.class file in the mainTest directory

To run it as a test

```
java -cp . mainTest/phpFunction 25
```

Where 25 is the argument you want to pass, the output will be

```
$ java -cp . mainTest/phpFunction 25
50
```

Comment: I hope that helped igtoth, let me know if you have any issues - sounds like java jdk (at least oracles version) can be a pain to get installed on Ubuntu - also, while I havent touched PHP in years,, might be able to help out with the shell_exec command.  Have a great evening!

Comment: thank you very much ... please look my code ABOVE.. I got few errors when trying to compile.. I tested yours and worked fine. @JGlass

Comment: Did you get it figured out?  You mention your code and errors, I see that you added code to your question, but then removed it?

Comment: Yes @JGlass .. thank you... its working partially ... now after compilation I got:

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /tmp/javac/liblib-superplacas.so: /tmp/javac/libm.so: invalid ELF header`

Comment: Are you trying to use JNI or JNA from your java code?  Does your code compile 100% - but you get that error when trying to run it?  superplacas seems to be a ?brazilian? website and for some reason the java code or JVM is trying to load some shared objects ".so" libraries - possibly related [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30839952/exception-in-thread-main-java-lang-unsatisfiedlinkerror-no-lpsolve55j-in-java) might need to try that LD_LIBRARY_PATH if the java code is doing something native.

Comment: And the libm.so, I find mention [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_lib.html)

Comment: @igtoth questions often lead to new questions, however it appears that this one is answered.  IF you have a new question regarding `/tmp/javac/libm.so: invalid ELF header` or similar I suggest you open a new question. Don't forget to upvote/accept the answer that helped you the most on this question. Regards!